# How do I set my keyboard setting for the thinkpad x270?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I am on Kubuntu, how do I set my keyboard settings for thinkpad x270? (there is no setting for this, I can only see generic 101 key PC)

Comment: In case you aren't aware, 16.10 is EOL as of July 20, 2017: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29. End of life versions aren't supported here "unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release." See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: There are a few thinkpad options, but I'd suggest that you start with trying the generic **pc105**.

Comment: @DKBose: Since this kind of question is version independent, I edited it and removed "16.10".

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson pc105 doesn't map properly either..